# How to get floats from text file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file

Hi I am new to python and I have a textfile .txt with the following structure:

```
Text1     31332.22342
Text2     293023.32323
Text3     32332.32323
```

What is the easiest way to get those numbers into an array? Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You can read the file and split it into a a list, then iterate through the list and try to convert to a float, if its successful then add it to the floats list. like the following:

```
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split()
        floats = []
        for elem in data:
            try:
                floats.append(float(elem))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        print floats
```

output:

```
[31332.22342, 293023.32323, 32332.32323]
```

Comment: Maybe consider just catching `ValueError`, since this is expected when `float()` fails. Right now all other errors are ignored as well.

Comment: Why do you split the file? Why not just iterate over lines?

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!

Comment: @Mark as Christian mentioned, you might wanna catch `ValueError` only instead of general `except`

Answer (score 2):

You also can use [numpy genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) function. something like this:

**text_file.txt**

```
Text1     31332.22342
Text2     293023.32323
Text3     32332.32323
```

**python  shell**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> numbers = np.genfromtxt('text_file.txt', usecols=1 )
```

output

```
[  31332.22342  293023.32323   32332.32323]
```

Comment: Doesn't this read in all numbers in the text file? As the file is quite big, I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

To get propert validation of your data type try this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("test.txt", usecols=1, dtype=float)
```

**Output:**

```
[  31332.22342  293023.32323   32332.32323]
```